# Delete multiple rows by sql statement "delete from tableName" whereas TRIGGER "After Delete" had applied on that

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-delete

I have applied "After Delete" trigger on one table, below is the script:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[onDelete_N_UR]
   ON  [dbo].[Notification_UnRead]
   AFTER delete
AS 
BEGIN


SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @roid int 
set @roid=(select ReachOutID from deleted(nolock) 
where  deleted.NotificaionType='reachoutlike')


update CACHE_Reachout 
set CACHE_Reachout.LIKEcount=(select [dbo].[getReachout_Notification_Count](@roid,'like') ) 
where CACHE_Reachout.ReachOutID=@roid
```

END

Now I am trying to delete some rows in bulk using following sql statement:

```
delete from  Notification_UnRead where Notification_ID=****
```

And it's  giving me error

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."
```

How can I delete multiple rows using above delete statement when delete trigger applied on it .

Comment: That error message is very explicit.

Comment: Your delete query does not seem to use a subquery, unless those **** translate to a subquery and not a static value. You need to post the complete SQL of your trigger here, to get any help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[onDelete_N_UR]
  ON [dbo].[Notification_UnRead]
  AFTER DELETE
AS BEGIN


     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     DECLARE @roid INT
     SET @roid =
     (
          SELECT TOP 1 ReachOutID
          FROM DELETED d
          WHERE d.NotificaionType = 'reachoutlike'
     )


     UPDATE CACHE_Reachout
     SET CACHE_Reachout.LIKEcount = dbo.getReachout_Notification_Count(@roid, 'like')
     WHERE CACHE_Reachout.ReachOutID = @roid

END
```

Or try this (**more preferably for using**) -

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[onDelete_N_UR]
  ON [dbo].[Notification_UnRead]
  AFTER DELETE
AS BEGIN

     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     UPDATE t
     SET LIKEcount = dbo.getReachout_Notification_Count(d.ReachOutID, 'like')
     FROM CACHE_Reachout t
     JOIN DELETED d ON t.ReachOutID = d.ReachOutID
     WHERE d.NotificaionType = 'reachoutlike'

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
set @roid=(select ReachOutID from deleted(nolock) 
where  deleted.NotificaionType='reachoutlike')
```

Or

```
    set CACHE_Reachout.LIKEcount=
    (select [dbo].[getReachout_Notification_Count](@roid,'like') ) 
    where CACHE_Reachout.ReachOutID=@roid
```

is returning more than 1 row of data.

Raj

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[onDelete_N_UR]
ON [dbo].[Notification_UnRead]
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN

     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     DECLARE @roid INT
     SET @roid =
     (
          SELECT TOP 1 ReachOutID
          FROM DELETED(nolock)
          WHERE DELETED.NotificaionType = 'reachoutlike'
     )


     UPDATE CACHE_Reachout
     SET CACHE_Reachout.LIKEcount =
     (
          SELECT [dbo].[getReachout_Notification_Count](@roid, 'like')
     )
     WHERE CACHE_Reachout.ReachOutID = @roid

END
```

Comment: Although this silences the error, it doesn't fix the logical problem (unless every row with the same `Notification_ID` has the same `ReachOutID`) - you're selecting an *arbitrary* `ReachOutID` from `deleted`, and ignoring all the others that were also deleted. You need to write code that respects that `deleted` is a pseudo-table containing *multiple* rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[onDelete_N_UR]
   ON  [dbo].[Notification_UnRead]
   AFTER delete
AS 
BEGIN


    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @roid int 

    CREATE TABLE #TempTable (ReachOutID INT)

    INSERT INTO #TempTable (ReachOutID)
    select ReachOutID from deleted(nolock) where deleted.NotificaionType='reachoutlike'




DECLARE @getAccountID CURSOR
SET @getAccountID = CURSOR FOR
SELECT ReachOutID
FROM #TempTable
OPEN @getAccountID
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getAccountID INTO @roid
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

update CACHE_Reachout set CACHE_Reachout.LIKEcount=(select [dbo].[getReachout_Notification_Count](@roid,'like') ) where CACHE_Reachout.ReachOutID=@roid



FETCH NEXT
FROM @getAccountID INTO @roid
END
CLOSE @getAccountID
DEALLOCATE @getAccountID

    drop table #TempTable
END
```